# How to mitigate the risks of buying a stake in a company

Tags: united-kingdom, starting-out-investing, shares

I work for a small Limited company in the UK that's owned 100% by the MD. I'm one of the management team so have some influence over the direction of the company, but no directorship or ownership stake yet.

I've been offered the opportunity to buy a 1% of the shares in the company. They would not be ordinary shares - they'd be a class of shares where the value would only be realised when the company is sold (which is the plan within the next 10 years).

Aside from whether the amount they want for 1% is reasonable (which I believe it is), I'm after some advice on this. I am already aware of some of the risks of this:

- The company could go bust of course and I'd lose it all.
- If I want to leave the company I may only get my original investment back - or possibly less if the company has devalued (which the owner could do deliberately if he wanted to!).
- The owner may decide not to sell, leaving my investment stuck in there indefinitely.
- The owner could decide to dilute the shares by issuing a large number of shares to himself, diluting my shareholding to <1%.

So what I'm after is some advice on the risks and what can generally be done to mitigate them if anything (especially the share dilution as this is most out of my control) - I assume via a shareholders' agreement or similar. Assume that I want to find a way to make it work rather than find reasons not to invest. I asked some of these questions a while ago to a solicitor who seemed to indicate that he'd review and firm up a shareholders' agreement for about £2-3,000 which is way over what makes sense in this context.

So, what do you advise?

(Posting anonymously for privacy reasons but I'll keep an eye on the thread)

Comment: Are you sure they are offering you shares in the company and not stock _options_?

Comment: Yes, 1% of shares in the company in exchange for a sum of money I'll pay the MD.

Comment: Are they limited liability?  The UK is the jurisdiction where Lloyds of London "names" still have unlimited liability.  If 2000 pounds is "too much" for true professional advice, then this means the amount you would invest would be an amount you could "afford to lose" even if you were not that happy about it?

Comment: @user662852 - it's a Limited Company yes. You're right, that the amount is something I could "afford to lose" although it would not be nice to do so! So I'm looking to mitigate the risks but without spending a significant proportion of the proposed investment (remember, it's a small company) on legal fees (which I definitely won't ever see come back!).

Comment: I'm confused about the actual meaning of the 'shares' you would own.  Is this an (as mentioned in earlier comments) an option, allowing you to receive a number of shares at the time of sale of the business (but giving you no ownership prerogatives or dividends, if any, until that time), or (almost equivalently) a derivative contract, just giving you the cash value of 1% of shares when the shares are sold?  ...con't...

Comment: ...On the other hand, it could be that you actually buy 1% of the regular stock (with ownership prerogatives, dividends, etc.) but with a side contract preventing you from selling the shares until the business is sold.  The latter would give you some advantages.You'd get dividends (if any) and if the stock was split you'd get your shares split, too.  You could (possibly, you'd have to see a lawyer) have some recourse if the owner did something sleazy like borrowing lots of money and paying themselves an extra large salary, it would be a violation of their fiduciary duty toward the stockholder.

Comment: Thanks for the input - appreciated. To be honest I don't know the difference between a stock options, a derivative contract and shares - it may legally be one or more of those, but I wouldn't know. I guess I'll just need to find a lawyer and work through it - preferably with lower fees!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any way to "mitigate the risk" other than being very involved in the company's operation, or selling off the share (which means losing the potential gains as well).... presuming that it's already incorporated so you bear no personal liability should it collapse or be sued. You'd be becoming part owner of the company, with all that implies.

Comment: So there's no way to mitigate against share dilution? Of the listed issues this seems like the one that would be most out of my control as a manager in the company - as the owner could just do this at their will. 
I guess the same could be true of devaluing the company deliberately to avoid me getting a payout on sale, but that would seem to be against his best interests...

Comment: Not without owning a large enough share to vote that down, or some contractual paperwork in place preventing it. The latter needs a lawyer, which would be the next step if you're still interested in any case.